# Request module: what if server doesn't respond?

Tags: node.js, request

The Node JS request module has a callback containing that fires whenever the response is received, but what if the server doesn't respond?

I will illustrate it with an example.

My code looks like this:

```
request(TARGET_URL, function (error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) doSomething()
})
```

So, again: **what if the server doesn't respond**? How can I avoid the program execution to halt if the TARGET_URL server doesn't respond?

Answer (score 0):

In this case a callback function still will be called after some time, but its first argument won't be empty. Quoting [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#timeouts):

> There are two main types of timeouts: connection timeouts and read
>   timeouts. A connect timeout occurs if the timeout is hit while your
>   client is attempting to establish a connection to a remote machine
>   (corresponding to the connect() call on the socket). A read timeout
>   occurs any time the server is too slow to send back a part of the
>   response.
>
> These two situations have widely different implications for what went
>   wrong with the request, so it's useful to be able to distinguish them.
>   **You can detect timeout errors by checking `err.code` for an `'ETIMEDOUT'`
>   value.** Further, you can detect whether the timeout was a connection
>   timeout by checking if the `err.connect` property is set to `true`.

```
request.get('http://10.255.255.1', {timeout: 1500}, function(err) {
    console.log(err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT');
    // Set to `true` if the timeout was a connection timeout, `false` or
    // `undefined` otherwise.
    console.log(err.connect === true);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Note that `{ timeout : 1500 }` part: with this approach you can set a specific time for a specific request to be processed.